# How clear the rails console history

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I need to eliminate the previous commands saved in rails console

I want that to enter to rails console no exist previous comands

I am use rvm and ubuntu 12.04

I found a file called  ~/.irb-history, but I'm not sure if is that file

Comment: Well, what happens if you remove it? Or change its name?

Comment: I clear the contents that file and the rails console historial was deleted Is that file then?. Really I have not idea where rvm maintains those records